# Loading google maps static images into flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, google-maps, cross-domain-policy

I'm trying to load images from google maps static images api into flash. When I attempt to load them flash complain about sandbox issues. Even after I try and load the policy file from google.

`Security.loadPolicyFile("http://maps.googleapis.com/crossdomain.xml");`

Is there any way around this? or is it simply impossible to load images in this fashion?

Comment: Are you testing this locally or from a web server?

Comment: Please show some code. Loading an image from a different domain should not cause a security sandobx error. However, if you try to access the bit map data of such an image, it will generate a security error.

Comment: I did solve this, you are correct, I was using a loader class and it was trying to check the status, which I guise involves accessing the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        var loader1:Loader = new Loader();
        var lctx1:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(true);
        loader1.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, doImgInit);
        loader1.load(new URLRequest("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=14&size=600x400&maptype=satellite&sensor=false&scale=4"), lctx1);
    private function doImgInit(evt:Event):void
    {
        trace("DO IT")
        // get a reference to the LoaderInfo object in which the image is loaded
        var lInfo:LoaderInfo = evt.target as LoaderInfo;

        // this variable is used as reference to the image in the end.
        var dO:DisplayObject;

        // try to access the "content" property of the loader, if it works, there is a crossdomain.xml file. 
        try{
            dO = lInfo.loader.content;
        } 

        // if there wasn't one, we need to put the loader inside another object in order to manipulate it
        catch(err:SecurityError)
        {
            // create a new Sprite to contain the loaded image
            var sprt:Sprite = new Sprite();
            // add the loader to the sprite
            sprt.addChild(lInfo.loader);
            // get a reference to this sprite in the dO variable
            var dO:DisplayObject = sprt as DisplayObject;
        }

        // from here on you can do anything to the dO variable, rotate it, draw it unto a bitmapData, move it around.. 
        // but first don't forget to add to to some container that is on the stage so you can see it!   
    }
```

Comment: have you been able to draw the bitmapdata without running into problems sandbox problems?